# Nuget errors in MVC project

Tags: c#, nuget, elmah.mvc

I am getting below nuget errors in MVC project and I tried uninstalling/installing packages.

[image]

Comment: Yeah so someone updated that package and committed their packages.config but forget to commit their .csproj, or vice versa. Read [ask] and show what you have tried. Analyze and compare the packages.config and the .csproj.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the solution in Visual Studio and selecting Restore NuGet Packages, other suggestions here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore-troubleshooting